# Is there any difference between widgets (used in order to manage menus) and register_nav_menus() in terms of performance?

Tags: menus, widgets, performance

I plan to add in the footer of my website 4 menu areas (such as "About us", "Services", etc.), each area with 3 or 4 links.

In terms of performances, should I use **widget functionality** to manage and publish menus or should i use **register_nav_menus()** ? Is there any difference in terms of **performance** between them ?

Comment: The difference between the two would be _incredibly_ small. Performance is not the criteria you should use to choose between them.

Comment: This is micro-optimisation, it will not yield performance gains worth your time. Any gains you get may be wiped out by the data centre being 1C hotter or your computer opening a menu at the same time, utterly insignificant. There are far better things to spend your time on if you want a faster site, like eliminating HTTP queries, frontend writes, and fixing slow DB queries